# Unit Testing Connection to Cloud Storage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using C# and I wanted to unit test the connection to cloud storage, the basic parameters it gives me.   I cannot work out how to write a meaningful test for it.

Could somebody please show me what i should be writing just to test the connection?

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("SkinImagingCloudConnectionLayer.dll")]
public void SetUpConnectionTest()
{
    CloudConnection_Accessor.SetUpConnection();
    Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
}

private static void SetUpConnection()
{
    // Use the local storage account.
    //cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
    cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*****;AccountKey=LBQ8k1myLKUKry03******************Itid+9BpV45GHAIWQ==");
    #region Select (or create) a Blob Container... it's like a Folder!
    // Create the blob client, which provides
    // authenticated access to the Blob service.
    blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Get the container reference.
    blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("cp300");
    // Create the container if it does not exist.
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

    // Set permissions on the container.
    containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
    // This sample sets the container to have public blobs. Your application
    // needs may be different. See the documentation for BlobContainerPermissions
    // for more information about blob container permissions.
    containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
    blobContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What aspect of the connection are you trying to test? Do you want to connect to the real thing or a stub?

Comment: I want to show that the connection exists between the program and the cloud storage itself

Comment: What is SetUpConnection() supposed to do? What can you test as a sucessful artifact of it being called? Also, since you're working with 2 interfaces, this is really an integration test. Why do you have the Assert.Inconclusive statement? What do you mean by "The connection exists"? That it's open, online, available, in use... what do you mean?

Comment: Yeah, sorry my knowledge of all this is very vague, ill add the code from the oter class, that might clear things up a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it clear. You are creating an Integration test - not a unit test :o)